# SSRS input parameters with null values trigger report itself

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

when we have input parameters for stored procedures like @fromDate @toDate and both allow null values, when run the report it trigger itself and do not stop for user input. We have reports in crystal which not only shows parameters but also give user a opportunity to enter or check the checkbox for null value to pass. How could we achieve this SSRS?

Comment: what are the default values for the parameters ?

Comment: nothing (null) but in st.proc. logic is if both null then fill back date one month and today. Full month period.

Answer (score 0):

You Can do this by checking the Allow null value option in the parameter propreties (General)

[image]

Comment: Thanks but if you check for all parameters then report will trigger without stopping for parameter values. In Crystal it shows all parameters first before run. In SSRS you see this null check box checked and report runs for all values and waste time and resources.